# Convert into passive voice

Tags: passive-voice

> He stopped me from entering into the room by taking the help of his brother.

How do I change this sentence into passive? Do we change the phrase "by taking the help of his brother" into passive or keep it as it is?

Comment: Matrix clause passivisation would yield the somewhat unnatural _I was stopped by him from entering the room by him taking the help of his brother_.

Comment: More natural would be _I was stopped from entering the room by him taking the help of his brother_.

Comment: It's not very idiomatic to include ***into*** after ***to enter***, except in certain "frozen form" contexts such as *entering into a [legal] contract*. And it would normally be ***with*** rather than ***by taking***, so in total *He stopped me [from] entering the room with his brother's help.* Where that final adverbial clause could be "fronted" to avoid any suggestion that ***I*** (the nearest immediately preceding pronoun) was being (unsuccessfully) helped by his brother: *With his brother's help, he stopped me entering the room .*

Comment: Is this a question from a text book  Please acknowledge the source of the quote.  Is this an exercise in "changing to the passive"  - if not, I ask "why change to the passive?"

Comment: I find "taking the help of" to be extremely unnatural. "asking for help from" or "receiving/getting help from" sound better. Also "with the help of".

Answer (score 2):

Don't say:  "**...by taking the help of his brother**".  Most English speakers will think this usage is wrong or not natural.

Instead, say:  "**...with the help of his brother**".

To say the entire sentence in the passive voice:  "**I was stopped from entering the room by him and his brother.**"

Mentioning the brother's help should come at the end of the sentence.  Do not put it at the beginning as a separate clause.

Answer (score 0):

Matrix clause passivisation would yield the somewhat unnatural

> I was stopped by him from entering the room by him taking the help of his brother.

More natural would be:

> I was stopped from entering the room by him taking the help of his brother

It's not very idiomatic to include **into** after to **enter**, except in certain "frozen form" contexts such as *entering into a [legal] contract*. And it would normally be **with** rather than **by taking**, so in total *He stopped me [from] entering the room with his brother's help.* Where that final adverbial clause could be "fronted" to avoid any suggestion that I (the nearest immediately preceding pronoun) was being (unsuccessfully) helped by his brother:

> With his brother's help, he stopped me entering the room.

This could be passivised as

> With his brother's help, I was stopped by him from entering the room.

Comment: Hi! I upvoted your good answer! We counterbalanced the downvote! Your good answer does not deserve a downvote!